# Rails: date validation or nil/blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

In my event model, I (used to have) these lines for validation:

```
validates_date_of :begins_at
validates_date_of :deadline
validates :deadline, :date => {:before_or_equal_to => :begins_at}
```

Now I wanted to have both fields optionals, to cater for "undetermined" events. However, if I have

```
validates_date_of :begins_at, :allow_nil => true
validates_date_of :deadline, :allow_nil => true
validates :deadline, :date => {:before_or_equal_to => :begins_at }, :allow_nil => true
```

these tests fails (thanks to **leemachin**'s suggestion, I refactored)

```
it "should accept nil as begining_date"  do
@event.begins_at=nil;
@event.should be_valid
end

it "should have valid deadline"  do
@event.deadline="Not a date";
@event.should_not be_valid
end
```

whereas these pass

```
it "should accept both dates as nil"  do
@event.begins_at=nil;
@event.deadline=nil;
@event.should be_valid
end

it "should accept nil as deadline"  do
@event.deadline=nil;
@event.should be_valid
end
```

I have a workaround in the program logic that sets deadline to nil whenever the start date is nil, but the  test fails nevertheless.
Any ideas?

Thanks

**PS: Using gem "date_validator", "~> 0.6.3"***

Comment: You should consider refactoring your second test into individual cases. You can then more easily determine which assertion fails, and make your test more readable.

Comment: I did that, and in fact I found a partial solution, that works though not perfect.